# Blank page building Vue on NodeJS Express Backend

Tags: node.js, express, vue.js, vuetify.js

The build on the Vue side works without a problem. Then I copied all the files in the **dist** folder to the **public** in the backend-side (Node.js - Express).
When I run the server I get a blank html page, no matter what route I try to go.
The only error I found it's in the **Sources** tab in the inspector:

[image: Error found in Sources tab]

I read another posts and I already try another things like adding **.vue** extensions on the imports or add the **./** in the scripts imports in the **index.html**. Any idea what's happening? Thank you